# Checking existance of dynamic value before update/insert

Tags: sql-server, function, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

I am trying to mass update a table column with values but I need to get the query to check whether this value already exists. If it does then to make the relevant changes before checking again and updating the table.

The database primarily holds staff information and I need to create a unique username, the script to create the username is :

```
select upper(LEFT(first_name,1))+LEFT(surname,3)+'1' 
from staff_test
```

If this was used for an example user it would generate a `username` of `ABit1` for user `Andrew Bithell`. What I need it to do is check to see if there already is a `ABit1` `username` in the `STAFF_TEST` table and if so change Andrews username to `ABit2` as the usernames have to be unique before it moves onto the next user.

I have created another table which lists all the current usernames splitting the existing usernames into 2 columns, so they display in this table as

```
column1 | column2
------------------
ABit    |1
```

I have experimented with a function and I am now thinking a Merge statement might be the way to go.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Use row_number can generate all the unique names at once:

```
select 
    upper(LEFT(first_name,1))+LEFT(surname,3)+ 
        rtrim(row_number() over (partition by upper(LEFT(first_name,1))+LEFT(surname,3) ))
   ,first_name
   ,surname
from staff_test
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform an up front check to see if there are any clashes:

```
SELECT  UPPER(LEFT(first_name, 1)) + LEFT(surname, 3) + '1' AS username ,
        COUNT(1) counter
FROM    staff_test
GROUP BY UPPER(LEFT(first_name, 1)) + LEFT(surname, 3) + '1'
HAVING  COUNT(1) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
```

This will return each username on your staff table, grouped by the username, along with a count of how many occurrences there are of each.

You can either sanitize the data if that's what you're looking to do, otherwise I would suggest, appending an `Id` column value or some other unique value per record instead of `1` on the end.